# Deallocating using deallocators

Tags: c++, allocator

I have a question about allocators. So allocator_traits provides functions `destroy` and `deallocate`. Is it safe calling  `std::allocator_traits<>::destroy(a,p)` and then `std::allocator_traits<>::deallocate(a,p,1)` assuming `a` is `std::allocator` and `p` is a pointer to the allocated memory? My concern is since `std::allocator.deallocate()` is implemented via `delete` would it actually calls the destructor twice?

Comment: Your concern is unjustified, and `std::allocator::deallocate` is not implemented that way.

Comment: It doesn't use `delete`, it uses [`::operator delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete), which is totally different.

Comment: very well, so am I supposed to call `allocator.destroy` before `allocator.deallocate`? I will further investigate  `::operator delete`.

Comment: @JiříLechner - Yes, you use `destroy` to clear out the object. You might then later call `construct` to create a new object in the same space. Or `deallocate` when you don't need the memory space anymore.